# Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed.I am getting error?

Tags: android

I am not geeting any force close in application but this error is showing in logcat please suggest me how to solve this error?

I am using this

```
line no 210::public Cursor getreLaunchView() 
      {
     Cursor cursor = db.query(reLaunchView.TABLE,new String[] { reLaunchView.Launch_ID,          reLaunchView.Launch_CENTERLATITUDE,
           reLaunchView.Launch_CENTERLONGITUDE,reLaunchView.Launch_LATDELTA,reLaunchView.Launch_LONGDELTA,
           reLaunchView.Launch_ZOOMLEVEL},null, null, null, null, null);
   if (cursor != null) 
   {
     cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
     return cursor;
 }

01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.bluepal.android.parkable/databases/parkable.db, table = reLaunchView, query = SELECT _id, centerLatitude, centerLongitude, latDelta, longDelta, zoomLevel FROM reLaunchView
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at **com.bluepal.android.parkable.parkdatabase.getreLaunchView(parkdatabase.java:210)**
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at com.bluepal.android.parkable.Prakablescreen.databasefunction(Prakablescreen.java:663)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at com.bluepal.android.parkable.Prakablescreen.displayMap(Prakablescreen.java:563)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at com.bluepal.android.parkable.Prakablescreen$1.handleMessage(Prakablescreen.java:531)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-04 12:26:29.482: ERROR/Cursor(3479):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the cursor returned from getreLaunchView is being finalized (most likely because it's out of scope) but it hasn't been closed. Call close() on the cursor when you're done with it.